# JavaScript array content in html without .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and web development. I am trying to display contents of a few JavaScript arrays in html. From what I have read, using `.innerHTML` destroys all child elements.

I have 2 javascript arrays that I am querying from a REST API:

```
var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40];
var temp=[50, 60, 70, 80];
```

How do I display text in html that says, on each line:

Temperature was **10** degrees and humidity was **50**%

Temperature was **20** degrees and humidity was **60**%

... and so on.

Should I still use `.innerHTML`? If so, wouldn't it destroy all but the last line of the output? The output is being added to a `<div>` element, without a list or table.

Comment: Please create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example to illustrate your use case. It is not clear from your question how your DOM is structured: are you appending data to a list? A table?

Comment: You could always `create` and `append` the new content so it doesn't remove the existing child elements... https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_node_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var humid = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var temp = [50, 60, 70, 80];
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
  container.innerHTML += `<p>Temperature was ${temp[i]} degrees and humidity was ${humid[i]} % `;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

It just sample code.

If you want to explain, comment please.

Comment: An answer without any explanation or comments inside the code is realy a nogo @SO. Your Answer was accepted by the questioner, but please add some explanation for further visitors of this question.

Comment: @JoshuaK I can explain. but It is too hard for me.I have to spend a lot of time for explain. because I'm not good at English. I just want to help for questioner. honestly, I don't know what I explain this code? I just use `+=`.  Anyway, I'm so sorry. Next time I will try to explain more.

Comment: The issue with this is you're unnecessarily hitting the DOM with every iteration of the loop. It's much better to build up the HTML string first, then attach it to the DOM, once.

Comment: @Andy I know.. It just SAMPLE CODE. Please.

Comment: @Andy I don't want to spend time for this answer. I want to help for questioner. I don't want to make perfect code.

Comment: And it's great that you want to help. But I don't think teaching someone (who, I presume, is just learning JS) bad habits this early is good for you or them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways. First you could use appendChild with the createTextNode method. Or you can use innerHTML / innerText. Yeah you're right, they override all content, that is saved earlier, but... you can take the old content, append your new content and use innerHTML / innerText to set this combined content ;)

```
var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40];
var temp=[50, 60, 70, 80];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML + 'Temperature was '+humid[0]+' degrees and humidity was '+temp[0]+'%<br>';
// shorter:
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Temperature was '+humid[0]+' degrees and humidity was '+temp[0]+'%<br>';
```

If you want to append all:

```
var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40];
var temp=[50, 60, 70, 80];

for(i=0;i<humid.length;i++)
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Temperature was '+humid[i]+' degrees and humidity was '+temp[i]+'%<br>';
```

Comment: The issue with this is you're unnecessarily hitting the DOM with every iteration of the loop. It's much better to build up the HTML string first, then attach it to the DOM, once.

Comment: @Andy Sure. If there are 100.000 of array items, but not with a few hundred.

Comment: Why not get into the habit writing performant code even with small iterations?

Comment: @Andy the questioner is a completly beginner and your code uses arrow-functions, backtick strings, function chaining... that's your point of view in writing better and performant sample code? What's about being responsive to the questioner?

Comment: I never said my answer was better than any of the other code here. I merely pointed out that a couple of the answers, including yours, could be improved. With 4 almost identical answers here already I decided to write something different that I thought might interest then OP, concentrating on the different approaches that the OP could take.

Comment: @Joshua, couldn't agree more. I've looked at Andy's answer and it's full of concepts the questioner doesn't even know exist in the JavaScript language. His answer is certainly not a great one, considering the context.

Comment: @Andy don't be mad. I didn't mean it as an attack. But wanne hear a funny thing? your code is slower than mine :D [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/accessing-dom-benchmark)

Comment: Using a series of tests all with the same "mistake" in them is a really dishonest way to try and prove your point.

Comment: @Andy you mean the equal instead of the equal-concat? It's not a mistake. I made it because of the greater than 9 GB RAM consumption. Please feel free to write your own tests. It won't change anything on the result.

Answer (score 3):

This is the JS Implementation. Becomes much easier when using jQuery. Let me know if you want help with Jquery implementation.

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS

```
var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40]; var temp=[50, 60, 70, 80];
var container = document.getElementById("container");
humid.forEach((item, index)=> {
   let newElement = document.createElement("p");
   let textNode = document.createTextNode("Temperature was "+temp[index]+" degrees and humidity was "+ item+"%")
   newElement.appendChild(textNode);
   container.appendChild(newElement);
;})
```

Comment: it would be really helpful to know the jQuery implementation

Comment: var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40]; var temp=[50, 60, 70, 80];
humid.forEach((item, index)=>{
$("#container").append("<p>Temperature was "+temp[index]+" degrees and humidity was "+ item+"% </p>")
})

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can prepare your final html content in variable then add it to your html

```js
var humid=[10, 20, 30, 40]; 
var temp= [50, 60, 70, 80];
var text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i += 1) {
    text += `Temperature was ${humid[i]} degrees and humidity was ${temp[i]}% <br>`;
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) you can create new dom elements on the fly.

My proposal is to create a table and style it:

```js
var humid = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var temp = [50, 60, 70, 80];

var table = $('<table/>')
        .append($('<thead/>').append($('<tr/>')
                .append($('<th/>', {text: 'Temperature was'}))
                .append($('<th/>', {text: 'degrees and humidity was'}))))
        .append($('<tbody/>'));
humid.forEach(function (ele, idx) {
    table.append($('<tr/>')
            .append($('<td/>', {text: ele}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: temp[idx] + '%'})));
})
$(document.body).append(table);
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers. You *can* use `innerHTML`, but it means that you have to build up the HTML string by iterating over the arrays and concatenating the different outputs together. Something like this ES6 example which uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
function buildStr(temp, humid) {

  // Iterate over the array creating the string, returning a new array
  // with that string output
  return humid.map((el, i) => {
    return `Temperature was <b>${temp[i]}</b> degrees and humidity was <b>${humid[i]}</b>.`;

  // Joining that array of strings together with an html <br />
  }).join('<br />');
}

const main = document.querySelector('#main');
main.innerHTML = buildStr(temp, humid);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3we2cyy3/)**

For that to work in jQuery:

```
$('#main').html(buildStr(temp, humid));
```

Alternatively you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). It has various ways to add HTML to existing elements, one of which is `beforeend`.

So, if you didn't want to iterate and wanted to add the HTML one line at a time:

```
const main = document.querySelector('#main');

let html = `Temperature was <b>${temp[0]}</b> degrees and humidity was <b>${humid[0]}</b>.`;
main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

let html2 = `Temperature was <b>${temp[0]}</b> degrees and humidity was <b>${humid[0]}</b>.`;
main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html2);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/teeqfrep/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var humid = [10, 20, 30, 40];
    var temp = [50, 60, 70, 80];

    $.each(humid, function( index, value ) {
      $("ol").append("<li>Temperature was "+value+" degrees and humidity was "+temp[index]+"%</li>");
    });
});
</script>
```

TAG

```
<ol>
</ol>
```